# How to conceal zerowidth special characters like <U200C>

Tags: unicode, conceal

That character is used so much in Persian writing. And it makes the text difficult to read. I tried to make my terminal display it correctly but I couldn't I was wondering maybe I could use vim syntax concealing to get rid of it. Can I? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
:syntax match ZeroWidthNonJoiner "[\u200c]" conceal cchar=
```

You need to check `:h conceallevel`, I set it to `2` personally. Otherwise, you may not get conceal to work as you expect.

Comment: this is displaying  instead of the character. I want it to disappear

Comment: @yukashimahuksay there's no way to disappear characters afaik, you can only substitute for another visible one.

Comment: @yukashimahuksay maybe replacing for a whitespace is good enough.

Comment: intrestingly, I did that and also cleared the highlight and now it appears just as I want. without showing anything.